# Windows 8 Exchange Active Sync email client (other than Mail or Outlook)

Tags: windows-8, email-client

Do I have a choice outside of these two? I'm sure the Mail app is fantastic on a tablet, but I prefer a less than full screen client that supports flags and adding attachments through file explorer (rather than the touch-inspired big tiles) without going whole hog to Outlook.

My Googling only finds similar complaints about Mail's lack of functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate to the Mail App's appbar by right clicking in the newley created mail message.
See the first hit on Google e.g.: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-send-attachments-with-the-windows-8-mail-ap.html

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with sending attachments, but I'm looking for a client that allows me to use the file explorer (or whatever it's called) rather than the slow, graphical interface that's designed for touch, rather than speed.